# How to correct syntactical parsing error?

Tags: haskell

I'm writing a Car data type as an extension to an example: `data Car = Car{customers::[a]}` where `customers::[a]` is to show a list of customers who are riding the car. Then I have written a function of `ListCustomer` to store a list of all customers by converting the data from data set into a list.

I have written :

```
ListCustomer::Car->[a]
ListCustomer (Car{customers = [a]}) = [a]
```

and there is parsing error in the brackets. I have checked the brackets and they appear balanced.

Comment: Functions can't start with an upper case, that's where the parsing error comes from.

Comment: Thank you, @MikaelF have changed the function and there is now parsing error on the input as I mentioned in the edits in the question above.

Comment: @12356frank I'm not sure what you mean by the last paragraph of your question, but `{...}` is not valid syntax for a Haskell list. Try with `[...]`. It would also be helpful if you would include the data you entered and the error message you're getting.

Comment: @MikaelF, Haskell is a powerful language, the aim is to process customer data set and convert the format into a list. The set is a common way to store data.

Comment: Then it looks like your `listCustomers` should be something like `listCustomers = toList . customers`, with an import from Data.Set. Otherwise, you're just getting a list with a set as its first element.

Comment: @MikaelF with reference to your previous comment: when I tried [...] there is still parsing error on the first value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205465/discussion-between-123456frank-and-mikaelf).

Comment: I have undone your edit. Fixing the problem makes it a different question, which should be asked separately. If you fix the problem in this question, it looks like the answer is telling you how to fix a problem that doesn't exist.

Comment: the { } is not "set", it's Haskell's record syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the compiler is telling you is that it doesn't understand the function you're declaring, since functions in Haskell have to start with a lower case letter. This compiles:

```
listCustomer :: Car a -> [a]
listCustomer (Car{customers = [a]}) = [a]
```

I should add that this will throw a "non-exhaustive pattern" error if you use it with inputs like `Car [1,2]` or `Car []`, since Haskell interprets the pattern `customers = [a]` as "a list of one element in the customers field". One way to correct this is to simply remove the brackets from your function:

```
listCustomer (Car{customers = a}) = a
```

Now, `a` simply stands for "anything in the `customer` field". Note that your `listCustomer` function is redundant, since the record syntax already provides you with a getter for the `customers` field:

```
> customers $ Car [1,2]
> [1,2]
```

Comment: I don't think `Car` needs a show instance for your example to work